# Ionic3 Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground in android 9 devices?

Tags: ionic3, android-9.0-pie, background-mode

I have generated the android build but its not working in some Android version 9 devices in the android 9 version app is crashed after login.i got below error in the console.[image]

**Tested In Following devices:**

Oppo F11 Pro: app working not crashed.

Samsung, Nokia, MI: App crashed after login

**Tried Below solution**:

Add inside config.xml

**1st Solution**

> ```
> <platform name="android">
>     <config-file parent="./" target="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
>     </config-file>
> </platform>
> ```

```
2nd Solution : add in AndroidManifest.xml

> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"
> />
```

i tried each and everything but nothing worked for me can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

finally after 2 days i fixed above issue:

try below command.

```
$ ionic cordova platform rm android
$ ionic cordova platform rm ios
$ ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/tushe/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/background-mode

$ ionic cordova platform add android
$ ionic cordova platform add ios
```

If background-mode is not working set Below changes in the cordova-plugin-background-mode worked for me. Crash issue is resolved as well as background plugin is working fine.

In ForegroundService.java made below changes:

```
Add below import statement: import android.app.NotificationChannel;
```

b) Add below global variables:

```
public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_SERVICE = "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background";
public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_INFO = "com.package.download_info";
```

c) Replace keepAwake() method with below code:

```
private void keepAwake() {
        JSONObject settings = BackgroundMode.getSettings();
        boolean isSilent    = settings.optBoolean("silent", false);
        if (!isSilent) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                nm.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_SERVICE, "App Service", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT));
                nm.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_INFO, "Download Info", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT));
            } else {
                startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, makeNotification());
            }
        }

        PowerManager powerMgr = (PowerManager)
                getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerMgr.newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "BackgroundMode");
        wakeLock.acquire();
}
```

**Add below in AndroidManifest.xml file:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

**In code where I invoked background mode plugin, used disableWebViewOptimizations option on activate:**

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.on('activate', function() {
       cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();
 });
```

Above procedure worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Capacitor then you can use this

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>`